# Auto-sizing CSS grid images?

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid, responsive-images

I'd like to try and get my grid images to scale down with the viewport at a certain screen width, but am unsure how to do it and manage to keep the integrity of the actual grid's layout. I currently have a grid with many different sized images and rows and would like to maintain the same layout/grid structure throughout all devices (desktop, tablet, mobile etc).

Is there a way to have my entire grid and all of its images shrink with the viewport the in a similar way to this link?
[Responsive Image](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_responsive)

I understand that is typical with setting the width to 100% and height to auto, but when I apply that to my grid's  tags, I lose height on the images. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Here is an example of some code I'm working with:

```
.image-gallery {
width: 100%;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: auto;
grid-gap: .5rem;
grid-template-areas: 
'img-16 img-17 img-27'
'img-16 img-18 img-27'
'img-16 img-19 img-27'
}
// Styling applied to these template-areas are only background images
```

To get my images to the size I desired, I had to set a height, which is where I am wondering how I can get this type of interaction with my images & a height of auto.

```
.image-gallery a {
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 16rem;
 }
```

Comment: paste your code here please

Comment: Have you tried to set all the img tags to `max-width: 100%`

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov posted -- thank you for the heads up

Comment: @Samakaab I believe so, but I don't think that did much. I probably screwed up the formatting of this grid somehow

Comment: I want to take a look at your mesh. can you insert html?